# Difference between ternary (question mark operator) in coffeescript and in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this line in my code:

```
de: (_.max(data, (product) -> product.prices.de )).price.de
```

I want firstly to check that the `product.prices` is defined, if it is defined return `product.prices.de` otherwise return 0.
In javascript I would write something like this:

```
angular.isDefined(product.prices) ? product.prices.de : 0
```

but when I am trying the same thing in coffeescript the coffeelinter is not accepting it. Any hints?
Is there difference between coffeescript and javascript in the use of query operator?

**Edit:**

I could write

```
de: (_.max(data, (product) -> product.prices?.de )).prices.de
```

but in that case if `product.prices` does not exists the function returns null and not 0

Comment: `product.priced ?` will check if it's falsey not if it's defined: for example `""` is also falsey - all objects are truthy but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: true, lets say that is angular.isDefined(product.priced)

Comment: Ah, I thought you were asking about the `??` operator in CoffeeScript (which does something akin to a `isDefined` check) and not the ternary operator. In CoffeeScript things are expressions so you'd just do `if product.prices then product.prices.de else 0`

Comment: Rethinking on it, you'd just do `product.prices?.de ?? 0`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes I know, but I am just wondering if there is something similar to javascript question mark operator, like `condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `product.prices?.de ?? 0` is not something acceptable by the coffeelinter, the `if then else` version is of-course ok, but not what I was looking, it seems that this is the only case that javascript is more elegant (in my eyes), thx!

Comment: Yeah, they removed `??` at some point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ternary operator in CoffeeScript is simply an if condition since everything in CoffeeScript is an expression. So the following:

```
condition ? something : somethingElse
```

Becomes:

```
if condition then something else somethingElse
```

Note that in your case though you wouldn't write:

```
if product.prices then product.prices.de else 0
```

You probably want:

```
product.prices?.de or 0
```